# How to calculate impact of falling weights with zero distance and time at impact

Tags: forces, acceleration, stress-strain

The motivation for this question is building a power rack for my basement due to corona Virus and not being able to visit the gym, and want to make sure it can hold the weight I desire including the safety bars if I drop the barbell a distance with a given amount of weight. I am using Douglas Fir 4x4s.

Since Impact force is dimensionally equivalent to momentum and per guidance of other sites, I ran some example numbers. I am taking 136kg (300lbs) and dropping them .5 meters. I therefore calculate a velocity of about 3.1m/s { V = (2gd)^.5 } , therefore if there is zero time at impact and zero distance traveled, the max impact could be 421kgm/s correct?

There is an [online impact force calculator](https://www.gigacalculator.com/calculators/impact-force-calculator.php) and I enter the numbers and if I enter infinitesimal collision distances or collision times, it spits out a very high impact force. I would think the max force is above, and a greater than zero impact time or distance would only absorb the force.

I am using 3/4 in pipe as safety bars. See the [Buff Dudes design](https://www.buffdudes.us/blogs/news/47856513-diy-buff-dudes-power-rack) for what I am making. Yes I am using the English system of inches and pounds but I can convert. Dividing the force in half will give 210N per side assuming it falls equally- which it won't, and that will produce compressive force on each side primarily, and maybe a little tensile or other type if the fall is uneven.

I'm confident the bars and the setup can support the weight I will be using, primarily for squats and bench press, and I don't plan on dropping the weight from high heights if at all, so I don't anticipate any problems, but I'm very curious about the physics of force and how you would get exact numbers (given assumptions) and whether I did the math right above and why the online converter was giving me extreme numbers given an instantaneous impact.

Comment: I don't fully understand. You are assuming the impact occurs over no time?

Comment: Maybe that's where my error is but what I mean by no time is infinitesimal, i.e. .01 seconds). Are time and distance of deformation (the other option) correlated, or inversely correlated?